# Multiple Regular Expressions conditions to match a single one

Tags: regex

I have to figure out how to write a regular expression that will match 4 different kinds of expressions.

1. an expression that starts with a consonant, then a vowel(not y), a dash, 6 digits.
2. an expression that starts with 1-8 digits, then 2-4 characters
3. an expression that starts with 5 digits, a common, 5 more digits
4. an expression that starts with three digits, a colon, two characters, a '>' (greater than sign), 7 digits.

I would really appreciate if somebody helped me go about solving this. I've looked online at regex testers but I'm not sure how to use them much...

Comment: Which flavor (programming language) and what have you tried thus far?

Comment: `y` is not a vowel. Make sure your specifications are right.

Comment: This is pretty specific examples.

Comment: Can you use assertions ?

Comment: what I have tried so far is the following expression: [^AEIOU] | [1-9]?{8}|[1-9]{5} | [1-8]{3}[-] | [,] | [:] [1-9]?{6} | [1-9]?{5}[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{7} @degant

Comment: @Jan there is no specific programming language to the question and what I have tried so far is  : [^AEIOU] | [1-9]?{8}|[1-9]{5} | [1-8]{3}[-] | [,] | [:] [1-9]?{6} | [1-9]?{5}[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{7}

Comment: @Rahul in the english language sometimes Y is considered a vowel which is why I included in parenthesis not y.

Comment: @sln yes I know very specific making it very tricky. and assertions as in lambda? like look ahead ? yes.

Comment: Not tricky at all. The thing is if the regex engine is known, it can be leveraged using modifiers and other shortcuts. Otherwise, it has to be specifically spelled out to cover most all engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression. Make sure to use the case insensitive flag (`i`) to match lower and upper case characters:

```
(?:^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]-\d{6}$)|(?:^\d{1,8}[a-z]{2,4}$)|(?:^\d{5},\d{5}$)|(?:^\d{3}:[a-z]{2}>\d{7}$)
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/qyRrCz/2

---

According to your question, the regex matches those 4 parts:

1. `(?:^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]-\d{6}$)` → e.g. `CU-987654` or `BO-062021`
2. `(?:^\d{1,8}[a-z]{2,4}$)` → e.g. `1BB` or `18273645QZ`
3. `(?:^\d{5},\d{5}$)` → e.g. `12345,98765` or `35481,01257`
4. `(?:^\d{3}:[a-z]{2}>\d{7}$)` → e.g. `333:aa>1234567`
   `321:AZ>7777777`

Comment: Thank you ! I will test it out and confirm this is correct for any one else wondering :)

Comment: I am fairly new to regex what does the $ stand for?

Comment: `$` stands for end of string and `^` represents start of string

Comment: `^` and `$` requires the string to only contain the regex pattern. E.g. `^abc$` would only match `abc` and not `1abc2` or `abcdefg`.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to do it yourself.
In the mean time, you can look at it this way.

`^(?:[^\WaeiouAEIOU\d_][aeiouAEIOU]-\d{6}|\d{1,8}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{5},\d{5}|\d{3}:[a-zA-Z]{2}>\d{7})$`

Expanded

```
 ^
 (?:
      [^\WaeiouAEIOU\d_] [aeiouAEIOU] - \d{6} 
   |  
      \d{1,8} [a-zA-Z]{2,4} 
   |  
      \d{5} , \d{5} 
   |  
      \d{3} : [a-zA-Z]{2} > \d{7} 
 )
 $
```

Comment: Thank you! yes I want to try it on my own hence why I asked for help on how to go about solving.

Comment: Good luck in your endevours.